# Codename One - Text field changing size randomly

Tags: codenameone

We have two inputs on login screen. They are working fine in simulator but on Android device they are changing height randomly when being focused.

What can be the reason of this?

EDIT, more details on screenshots

Loaded screen:
[image: Loaded screen]
After gaining, losing focus on text fields:
[image: After gaining, losing focus on text fields]
Component tree inspector:
[image: Component tree inspector]

Comment: The details we'll need to answer this are: Screenshots in simulator, device, before/after. We will also need the Full layout hierarchy which can be expressed with the Component Inspector

Comment: Hi, I've added screenshots

Answer (score 1):

On android when a the Keyboard is showing the Form is getting a size changed event which cause the screen to re-layout.
Make the TextFields parent Container scrollable-Y it will cause the scroll to grow instead of resizing the components inside